# How can I read in M-bus metering data with an Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino, communication, c

I am trying to send data from a Kamstrup Multical 601 to an Arduino Uno using the [M-bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meter-Bus) protocol.

I am considering trying to use the [libmbus c libraries](https://github.com/rscada/libmbus) to do this. However, I do not have a lot of experience in c programming so was wondering if:

- you think this is a realistic/achievable approach?
- anyone could suggest an alternative/easier approach?

The main chip on the Arduino Uno is the Atmel Atmega382P-PU.

After getting the data to the Arduino I aim to perform some calculations and send data to an LCD (this I think I can do).

Comment: At first glance, it appears that those libraries are likely meant to run on a PC or at least high level software environment which talks to a gateway device, rather than on a microcontroller which is directly connected to the bus.  Your best bet would probably be to ask the authors/maintainers of the libraries if there are embedded platforms on which it runs and works with direct interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to have a lot of trouble converting that C library for use on the Arduino. As mentioned by Chris, it looks like it's for a bigger system like a PC, so you'll have to port it for use in an embedded system. It's feasible, but may be more work than you'd like.

I was able to find some [application](http://www.ti.com/sc/data/msp/databook/chp3.pdf) [notes](http://www.ti.com/sc/data/msp/databook/chp4.pdf) that use an MSP430 and a [bus transceiver](http://www.ti.com/product/tss721a). In this way you can write to the M-Bus using UART, which TI has [lots of code](http://www.ti.com/tool/msp430ware?DCMP=msp430ware&HQS=msp430ware) available for implementation. They even use an LCD for displaying read information. Putting your Arduino in place of the MSP430 should work in the same way, they both have UART which you can set to the appropriate baud rate. [This](http://www.m-bus.com/mbusdoc/default.php) will get you as far *how* to talk to your meter. Then all you really need to do is figure out *what* to say to your meter. [This page](http://www.m-bus.com/mbusdoc/md5.php) has a nice diagram for the data layer of the M-Bus protocol,
[image: frame descriptions for m-bus]
 Each of the rows represent a byte value you would write to your UART send register. As far as what your specific meter is expecting for each of these fields, that's going to take some digging. It looks like there may be some register information [here](http://kamstrup.com/media/22107/file.pdf). But that's all going to depend on what modules you have installed on your meter, which you didn't specify.

Comment: Great answer. However, unfortunately neither the Kamstrup meter or the TI M-bus transceiver can operate in "Master" mode - there must be at least one master in any M-bus network.

Comment: Also, just to note that the Kamstrup meter has the Type 67-07 M-bus module installed.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably turn the Arduino into an M-Bus master, but it would require some work and extra circuitry since it would have to provide the voltage needed for the M-Bus line etc.

If the meter is not connected to an M-Bus network already, easiest would probably be to acquire an M-Bus master like the Relay PW3 or similar and connect to that.

If the meter is already on an M-Bus network it might be easier to connect to it using the optic port. There are opto readers with USB connections that work for the job.

Do note that I think that the MC601 uses the KMP protocol if you connect to it through opto. The M-Bus module in the meter is a seperate module that communicates with the meter internally using KMP and spits out M-Bus.